# Android + how to interrupt the loop of handler(run())

Tags: android, handler

I have 4 Classes,

1. FirstActivity
2. Play_1
3. Play_2
4. Play_3

onClicking a button in `FirstActivty`, I'll go randomly to the remaining three activities.
For example, in the following code I came to `Play3.class`... I have set then handler to run for 3 seconds.
My problem is during the `run()` time of 3 seconds, if I click the `backButton`, it will go to `FirstActivity.class` and after 3 seconds of `run()` time , it is going to the random loop again (`Play_1`, `Play_2`, `Play_3`). Now, I want to go permanently to the `FirstActivity.class` only when I click `backButton`. What Should I do?

(NOTE: After completion of `run()` time of three seconds, I am happily going to home screen. But, During that `run()` Time only I want to Interrupt the loop and go back to the HOME screen.)

```
class listener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.play3_image1:
                bt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                try {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Random rand = new Random();
                            int x = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;

                            Intent intent = new Intent();

                            switch (x) {
                                case 1:
                                    intent.setClass(v.getContext(), Play_1.class);
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    intent.setClass(v.getContext(), Play_2.class);
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    intent.setClass(v.getContext(), Play_3.class);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0 ){
                Intent i = new Intent(Play_3.this,Example.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add boolean variable skipped = false; and populate it onBackPressed with true? Then just check if variable skipped == true before running handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Handler object provides other post methods that can help you:

- With `postAtFrontOfQueue(Runnable r)` you can post a runnable to be executed in the next loop.
- With `removeCallbacksAndMessages(Object token)` you can remove a given runnable  or message or with `null` parameter clean out the processing queue.

With these utilities you should be able to handle your state chanes pretty easily.

Note: since you are using the main thread looper, you should not call getLooper().quit() on your handler object as that would stop your application (if not crash it completely).

Comment: Hi, @allprog, I got them before also, But How to implement Is the question.Any how it worked for me finally this time.So thanks a lot for your help.          "removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)"Solved the small issue.